# How to provide WebView of React-Native-app with user authentication data?

Tags: reactjs, webview, react-native, firebase-authentication

I’m currently developing a web app using ReactJS and Firebase, it is going to be some kind of a forum.
Despite minor bugs, the ReactJS-part is done and works.

Currently, to provide a better user experience, I am working on hybrid apps with React-Native and implement OneSignal as a way to send push notifications everytime a user opens up a new thread or his/her own thread is commented.

My question;
is there a way to save time and 'recycle' my ReactJS-WebApp when loading it inside a React-Native WebView BUT providing the WebView with the user authentication data from the React-Native-login?

What I want to accomplish is being able to recieve push notifications (which needs the user to be logged into the app) without having him to login a second time inside the WebView.

[I read about those mixed hybrid apps when getting familiar with PhoneGap and how the folks at Basecamp thought about it, but I have no idea how to accomplish it. I think about the need of building a middleware/adapter/magic-thing to load different scenarios of my ReactJS-app depending on the request coming from an ordinary browser or an React-Native-app.] Thank you so much in advance!